Equation environment labeling (1) , to the right
The output of the following code is,
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
%%¥usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{color}
    
\usepackage{amscd} 
\usepackage{amsthm}   
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,cd}  % 追加: 矢印のライブラリ
\usepackage{float}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
               diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
               }
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\end{document}


Let me translate this to English:
The numbering '(1)' appears on the left side, but I want to move it to the right side. How can I do this?

\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

Off topic: amsart incorporates amsthm and loads amsmath by default.

As you've (re)discovered, the amsart document classes places equation numbers on the left by default. To override this default setting and place the equation numbers on the right instead, you need to load the amsart document class with the option reqno:
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 

